# How to use legacy Kendo

Tags: kendo-ui, reactjs

I'm using Kendo.UI v2013.3.1119.  I ran window.kendo.ui in the Chrome console and it returned various objects including "Alert" which I do not see in the [current API.](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/list-of-widgets).  In this same list I see "ButtonGroup", not "Button".

I'm working in legacy code and I suspect they have messed around with the KendoUI code.  There's no error, but that may be because of the legacy code integration.

I'm trying to execute this code in react and it's not working.

### window.kendo.ui console output

```
    Object {roles: Object, validator: Object}
ActionDropdown: (t,i)
Alert: (n,i)
AutoComplete: (t,u)
ButtonGroup: (n,i)
Calendar: (t,u)
ColumnMenu: (r,f)
ComboBox: (u,f)
ConfigurableInput: (n,t)
DatePicker: ()DateTimePicker: (n,t)Draggable: (n,t)DropDownList: ()DropTarget: (n,t)DropTargetArea: (n,t)Editable: (t,i)EmployeeSearchTextBox: (n,i)FilterMenu: (u,f)FormattedTextBox: (n,t)Grid: (r,u)Groupable: (h,c)GroupedDropDownList: (i,r)List: (t,i)ListView: (r,u)Menu: (t,f)Movable: (t)MultiSelect: (i,r)Pager: (t,o)Pane: (n)PaneDimensions: (n)PanelBar: ()Phone: (n,t)Popup: ()ProgressBar: (n,i)RangeSlider: (i,r)Reorderable: (e,o)Repeater: (i,r)Resizable: (n,t)SearchTextBox: (n,i)Select: (n,t)Selectable: (t,r)Slider: (t,i)Sortable: ()Splitter: (n,t)SubWindow: (n,t)TimePicker: (n,t)Tooltip: ()TreeView: (n,t)Upload: (t,i)UserSearchTextBox: (n,i)Validator: (n,i)VirtualScrollable: (n,t)Widget: (n,t)Window: ()plugin: (t,u,e)progress: (i,r,u)roles: Objectvalidator: Object__proto__: Object
```

Code I tried:

```
  runjQuery: function() {
    console.log('successfully called jquery function');

    //$("#editor").kendoEditor();
    $("p").text("DAA DAA DAA DUU DA DUMM DUU DA DUMM");
    console.log('made it to middle of func');//makes it here
    $("#testButton").kendoButton();//fail
    console.log('made it to end of func');
  },

  render: function() {    
    return (
      <div className="jumbotron">
        <h1>Absence Management</h1>
        <p>Time Off, Accruals and all the things</p>
        <input type="text" id="phone_number" />
        <button id="testButton">Vader</button>
        <label id="editor" />
        {this.runjQuery()}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Is the old API documentation available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my recollection there was no button widget in the 2013 version of Kendo UI. You had to add the Kendo CSS classes (i.e. `k-button`) and on-click functionality manually.

Comment: That certainly gave me a styled kendo button!  This works as a proof of concept.  Now if only I can get access to this old API so I can do other interesting things!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/wingspan/wingspan-forms

It's a form library for react which wraps kendo ui.

Comment: I don't understand why this helps.  I can't switch libraries.  This is legacy code I'm working with.

Comment: Well, I'm not totally sure what you're doing but since you are trying to use kendo ui in a react app, this library's implementation might provide some insight. It's production code that has been vetted. Depending on how much you want to integrate kendo with react state, it can be quite challenging... Also it was written around 2013 so if you look at the history, there might be some legacy api insight.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll look into it ty

Comment: You probably want runJquery to be called in componentDidMount so you can guarantee your DOM elements get rendered first.